# papers with monthly or weekly firm-level data

Tags: econometrics, data-request

Hello everyone I need to find some recent papers that use monthly or weekly firm-level data.
The constraint is that the papers come from any of the following journals:

- the journal of finance
- review of financial studies
- american economic review
- econometrica

Comment: Defining 'recent' may be helpful.

Comment: Preferably not older than 5 years